# Q: Neo4j-wrapper.conf. Can I put more information into the Wrapper configuration files?

Tags: windows, powershell, neo4j, wrapper

I'm working on updating the Neo4j windows installation process into Powershell and I was thinking that perhaps it could read/write neo4j windows service information from the `neo4j-wrapper.conf` configuration file.

The Windows wrapper conf has very little information that is related the windows service itself (in fact I think it has no information that is used in the creation, management and removal process!)

My intention is to have the relevant windows service information in the configuration file and then when calls such as Install or Stop are made, then the Service Name can be retrieved from there instead of via command line arguments.

My questions are;

- If I put more information into that configuration file, will it affect the linux wrapper?
- Is there any reason why I shouldn't put more settings into the configuration file (but only related to a Windows Service)?

Note - My changes would also support this PR;
https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/pull/4433

Thanks,
  Glenn.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is, in principle, yes. Putting extra stuff in that file wouldn't hurt anything.

But it's not ideal to have a single file that's used for different purposes on different platforms (I see the presence there of Linux-specific service stuff as a problem rather than something to copied).

The real solution, I think, is for each package build to provide its own copy of that file (or one derived from a common starting point).

Comment: So, as an interim method, if I confine the property that I'd used to just wrapper.name that should be ok.  As it's a property that already exists but it's just not being used.

But long term, the building of that file should be modified to be platform specific.

I also noticed that the windows-logging-properties file is included in the *Nix distributions.  It wouldn't cause an issue, but if we're going to the effort of one config file, it wouldn't be a stretch for more.

Comment: Yes, I think that's correct. And yes, package specific files like that are another reason to make the split.